# Swift Combine removeDuplicates() not working as expected

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to filter only .portrait and .landscape orientation 
and then apply distinctUntilChanged i.e. removeDuplicates()

But removeDuplicates() seems to be never called as my debugger never stops inside comparator

and onReceive callback is called.

```
 // MARK: - Publishers
    private var orientationChange = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
        .map { toOrientation($0) }
        .filter { filterOrientation($0) }
        //.removeDuplicates()
        .removeDuplicates(by: { o1, o2 in
           _ = filterOrientation(o1)
           _ = filterOrientation(o2)
            return false
        })
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

How to allow only .portrait, .landscape, .portrait, .landscape sequences 
and not .portrait, .portrait, .landscape etc

**Update**

I need to use this, but it adds unnecessary boilerplate code:

```
.onReceive(orientationChange) { orientation in
                guard orientation != self.lastOrientation else { return }
                self.lastOrientation = orientation
```

}

Here are internal implementations of helper functions

```
fileprivate func toOrientation(_ notification: UIKit.Notification) -> UIDeviceOrientation {
    (notification.object as? UIDevice)?.orientation ?? .unknown
}

fileprivate func filterOrientation(_ orientation: UIDeviceOrientation, orientations: [UIDeviceOrientation] = [.landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight, .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown]) -> Bool {

    return orientations.contains(orientation)
}
```

Comment: it seems to be called only one on first emission?

Comment: Could you add the contents of `toOrientation` and `filterOrientation`?

Comment: I think the problem is that I am using this publisher as private let on SwiftUI View. I think I should move it to @Observed ObservableObject

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution when using **Publishers** in SwiftUI View is to add **@State**

```
// MARK: - Publishers
    @State private var orientationChange = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
        .map { toOrientation($0) }
        .filter { filterOrientation($0) }
        .removeDuplicates()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Otherwise this publisher will be recreated on each view redraw so it loses orientation change events and cannot removeDuplicates as there is always one event emitted while rotating

Other way if you use `ViewModel : ObservableObject`  I think it will be good to move this publisher there and add @ObservedObject property in SwiftUI view.

Comment: This really violates how SwiftUI works, you basically forced your (view)model into your view. I really recommend what you also mentioned, putting your Publisher into your ObservableObject.

Comment: Yeah but it simple view where I really do not have ObservableObject (viewModel now) and @State seems to work for it. But if I have more complex View with ViewModel I definitely move this publisher to this Observable ViewModel